# How can i see with @designable this design on storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, ibdesignable

I'm using masking.

**My Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var seconImageView: UIImageView!


    let maskView = UIImageView()
    let maskView2 = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        maskView.image = UIImage(named: "Up")
        maskView2.image = UIImage(named: "Down")
        firstImageView.mask = maskView
        seconImageView.mask = maskView2
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        maskView.frame = firstImageView.bounds
        maskView2.frame = seconImageView.bounds
    }
}
```

**UIImageView Code:**

UIImageView class. I can't see this design. How can I do ? I added custom class but didn't work

```
@IBDesignable
class FirstImageView: UIImageView {

    var maskkView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutSubviews()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        layoutSubviews()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        maskkView.image = UIImage(named: "mask")
        mask = maskkView
        maskkView.frame = bounds
    }

}
```

**Storyboard:**

[image]

**Simulator:**

[image]

How can i see with @designable this design on storyboard.

Comment: Where is your `@IBDesignable` UIView code?

Comment: @matt updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added custom class but didn't work

I assure you that masking in `layoutSubviews` of an `IBDesignable` UIImageView does work. Example:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyImageView : UIImageView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let lay = CAShapeLayer()
        lay.frame = self.bounds
        lay.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds).cgPath
        self.layer.mask = lay
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

I *suspect* that the problem with your code is that you are attempting to load an image from the bundle with `UIImage(named:)` in your `IBDesignable` code; my guess is that that isn't going to work. `IBDesignable` code is just some stuff that runs at storyboard rendering time; it cannot behave as if it were truly the running app.

Comment: thanks sir :) but I'm using another triangle png image for masking. I'm trying to make a triangle. I can't do. How can I do ?

Comment: If I'm right that you can't load an image in an IBDesignable's code, you should do what I did in my example: draw the triangle shape itself as a UIBezierPath, in code.